# Отобразить объекты с последнего добавленого

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, symfony2, twig

Подскажите пожалуйста как отобразить объекты чтобы последний добавленный был первым. Сейчас все наоборот.

[image: Пример]

Нужно чтобы было не так как на картинке, а наоборот => 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.

Код твига

```
<section class="section section--donaters" data-section="donaters">
   <div class="section-body">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="donaters">
          <div class="section-title text--blue donaters-title">
             <h4 data-title>{{ ourDonaters.value }}</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="section-content">
            <div class="items-list" data-list>

             {% embed "donaters.twig" with donaters %} {% endembed %}

             {% if donaters.page_count > 1 %}
             <!-- pagination -->
             <div class="pagination text--center" data-pagination>
              <ul class="hidden" data-pages>
               {% for page in 1..donaters.page_count-1 %}
                 <li><a href="/donaters/{{ page }}">{{ page }}</a></li>
               {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn--white-orange btn--small btn--block btn--pager" data-button="pager">
              <span>Загрузить еще</span> <i class="icon icon-spinner"></i>
              </button>
             </div><!-- /pagination -->
           {% endif %}
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>
```

Код symfony

```
final public function getDonaters($page = 0, $onPage = 6)
{
 $items = $this->getObjects($this->_containerID, $this->_projectClassID, true, [$page * $onPage, $onPage]);
 $count = $this->getObjectsCount($this->_containerID, $this->_projectClassID);
        
 return [
 'items' => $items,
 'on_page' => $onPage,
 'page_count' => ceil($count / $onPage),
 'count' => $count,
  ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно ответ

```
final public function getDonaters($page = 0, $onPage = 6)
{
    $items = $this->getObjects($this->_containerID, $this->_projectClassID, true, [$page * $onPage, $onPage], ['o.sort' => 'desc']);
    $count = $this->getObjectsCount($this->_containerID, $this->_projectClassID);

    return [
        'items' => $items,
        'on_page' => $onPage,
        'page_count' => ceil($count / $onPage),
        'count' => $count,
    ];
}
```